# Como exibir aspas em echo no PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usa PHP + AJAX e me deparei com um problema chato.
O AJAX só reconhece a função se a mesma estiver assim:

```
onclick="remover_musica_ftp('0','Deposito de bebida'
);"
```

Estou usando o PHP para "imprimir" esses valores no browser assim:

```
echo "<a href='#excluir' class='button icon-trash' onclick=remover_musica_ftp('0','".$nomes."');  title='Excluir'></a>";
```

Tenho que usar o php pois estou fazendo um `foreach`.
Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quando a palavra contem espaços, o ajax simplesmente não responde, pois o código precisaria estar como no primeiro exemplo, só que quando adiciono a aspa `"` automaticamente o PHP passa a ser inválido, pois o mesmo `echo` se iniciou com uma aspa.
Alguém tem noção do que como devo proceder neste caso?
Se eu abrir o echo com um `'` dará erro do mesmo jeito, pois precisaria inverter o onclick do ajax que não permitiria o `'`nas funções.
Dê-me uma sugestão!

Comment: Precisa de escapar as aspas para o PHP perceber que essa "aspa" não é para o PHP.
Teste assim:

    `echo "<a href='#excluir' class='button icon-trash' onclick='remover_musica_ftp(\"0\",\"".$nomes."\");'  title='Excluir'></a>";`

Comment: Não sei se resolve, mas esta parte, `('0','".$nomes."')`, pode ser escrita como `('0','$nomes')`. O PHP faz o parse da variável quando está dentro de aspas duplas.

Comment: Mas não é necessário passar string com aspa dupla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa escapar `"`.

```
$nomes = 'nomes...';
echo "<a href=\"#excluir\" class=\"button icon-trash\" onclick=remover_musica_ftp( 0 , \"$nomes\" ); title=\"Excluir\">link</a>";
```

<sub>**Output**</sub>

```
<a href="#excluir" class="button icon-trash" onclick=remover_musica_ftp( 0 , "nomes..." ); title="Excluir">link</a>
```

Se o argumento anterior ao nome for numérico, vocênão precisa usar `'`

```
remover_musica_ftp( integer , "string" )
```

Comment: Eu havia me esquecido de escapar, realmente muito obrigado!

Comment: Também já esqueci muito e é chato não poder dar plique (')

Answer (score 7):

Quando você quer mostrar o mesmo tipo de aspas que está usando para enclausurar a string, você precisa escapa-la usando uma barra `\`

```
$string = 'aspas simples: \' e aspas dupla: " ';
$string = "aspas simples: ' e aspas dupla: \" ";
```

Uma situação que pode ocorrer é você ter que escapar uma aspa dentro de uma string já escapada, então será preciso colocar uma barra escapada, como no ex. abaixo:

```
echo '<a onclick="remover_musica_ftp(0,\'It\\\'s Name Is\');"></a>';

// retorno:
<a onclick="remover_musica_ftp(0,'It\'s Name Is');"></a>
```